# Expanding topbar on hover to show Nav links

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a topbar to expand on Hover to show hidden text which could be social media icons, nav links etc.

However I am unsure of how to hide the text as it is appearing on and over the div below.

This is my (simple) code

```
html

<div class = "top"> This is the top
<div class = "invisible">can you see me</div>
</div>


<div class = "container">
<div class = "left">left</div>
<div class = "right">right</div>


</div>


This is my css

.top {
width : 100%;
background : blue;
padding-bottom : 25px;
position : relative;
}

.invisible {
position : absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top : 90%;
}

.top:hover {
padding-bottom : 150px;
background : yellow;

}

.container {
display : flex;
}

.left {
width : 50%;
background : red;
}

.right {
width : 50%;
background : green;
}
```

As you can see the Can you see me is appearing over the "left" text before hovering

Comment: Are you looking for `display: none;`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element (`.top`) because it is the child, `.invisible` that is overflowing outside of `.top`.

```css
.top {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.invisible {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
}

.top:hover {
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"> This is the top
  <div class="invisible">can you see me</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```